# OpenLDAP : How to enable the memberOf overlay when the attribuType (memberof) already exists?

Tags: openldap

I would like to set up the `memberof` overlay. It cannot be loaded because the attributeType `memberof` already exists in a configured schema.

How to set it up by using the existing attributeType ?

> 5b4f0a2e register_at: AttributeType "( 1.2.840.113556.1.2.102 NAME 'memberOf' DESC 'Group that the entry belongs to' SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.12' EQUALITY distinguishedNameMatch USAGE dSAOperation X-ORIGIN 'iPlanet Delegated Administrator' )": Duplicate attributeType, 1.2.840.113556.1.2.102
>   5b4f0a2e memberof_initialize: register_at #0 failed
>   5b4f0a2e conn=1002 op=18 RESULT tag=103 err=80 text= handler exited with 1

Answer (score 0):

As you already noted some OpenLDAP overlays bring their own LDAP schema descriptions hard-coded in the overlay's C code and that might conflict with schema descriptions in the config file (aka *slapd.conf*) or config database (aka *cn=config*).

In this particular case it's not a big problem because the OID and the NAME matches excactly what [slapo-memberof](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-memberof) will install. So you can safely just remove the attribute type description for *memberOf* you currently have in the schema. (I guess you've imported that during a LDAP server migration from another vendor.)

Do not add *memberOf* to your object classes. If *slapo-memberof* is correctly configured (on all replicas!) it will maintain the attribute values.

When changing your schema and doing migrations I'd also recommand to use command-line tool *slapschema* to check whether the current database content still matches the schema descriptions.

Comment: I understand what you mean (regarding the safely remove of the attribute type) but i do not want to have inconsistancy data (privious data using the attribute memberof). How i can configure the overlay memberof by saying it to use the existing the attributeType memberof ?

Regards,

Comment: In this particular case you won't have a problem. That's why I said: "because the OID and the NAME matches excactly what slapo-memberof will install".

Comment: As suggested, i deleted the attribute type and i updated the schemas and classes where the attribute has been used (concretly i removed the attribute in the définitions). After adding the memberof overlay and restarting sucessfully the ldap service, i decided to update the previous schemas and classes by adding the memberof attribute. But i had an error because i want  to use an operational attribute. It means that i do not want to add it in the definition of classes because it is operationnal now?

Comment: Yes, do not add _memberOf_ to object classes. If _slapo-memberof_ is correctly configured (on all replicas!) it will maintain the attribute values for you. (Also added to answer.)